# How to make sure the GA4/Pixel events are successfully sent and only then handle actual purchase?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, facebook-pixel

We using `Google Analytics 4` and `Facebook Pixel` to keep records of visitors purchases, but I can't find any information about how to wait for those events results and only then redirect visitor (how to determine is those metrics are sent).

There should be a way to await all of them. **For example, when checkout is complete, we track the purchase event but we don't want to leave the page until it's fully tracked to ensure the web request isn't terminated.**

It's how the events called:

```
gtag("event", "purchase", { ... });
fbq("track", "Purchase", { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

gtag uses [beacons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) to send events which should be guaranteed to be sent on most browsers.